# Wordpress Editor add Template Fields?

Tags: wordpress, templates, editor, tinymce

I would like to give the user the ability to insert custom elements in the Wordpress editor such as an accordion panel item for example. Or a an element which has an certain class or an inline style margin for example without using the HTML editor. Only using the WYSIWYG editor.

Is there a comfortable way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create an own plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin) (this is not that difficult) and add one or more buttons to let users insert those things.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds great, but because of I have always NO time I would prefer a plugin. If nobody knows a plugin I will mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: problem here is that you got a somewhat specific wish - i fear there might not be a plugin available already for this